# I want to automate my angular build using pos-receive in background process

Tags: linux, git, angular, githooks

I want to automate my angular build using pos-receive and i want it to run in backgound process so I will not wait to finish the command.

I tried the following the following code on my post-receive but it doesn't work.

**post-receive**

```
#!/bin/bash
git --work-tree=/var/www/my-sample-app.com --git-dir=/var/repo/my-sample-app.com.git checkout -f master
cd /var/www/my-sample-app.com
ng build --prod >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

I also tried to create a separate executable script on usr/local/bin directory like this

**build-app-script**

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/my-sample-app.com
mkdir test-dir
ng build --prod
```

then on my post-receive i change the code

```
ng build --prod >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

to

```
nohup /usr/local/bin/build-app-script &>/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

the script seems working because it create a test-dir but the 
ng-build --prod 
command is not executing

Any idea why is not working? or any suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: `ng build --prod >/tmp/ng-build.log 2>&1 &` and watch /tmp/ng-build.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i figure out my problem, i have a vps server on digital ocean with 500mb of ram. So when i run the ng build --prod command the process get killed. I think because of the insuficient ram. Then after googling solutions i found this tutorial that will add an extra ram to your server and it works perfectly.
Ref: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04